# Поочерёдное выделение частей кругового чарта с выведением аннотации

Tags: javascript, highcharts

У меня на странице есть чарт написанный javascript'ом. Вот код:

```
var pieChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["pieData"]))
        }]
    });
```

Затем я по таймеру выбираю поочереди каждый кусок чарта и это работает, вот код функции:

```
var timeReload = 3;
    var timenow = 0;
    var i = 0;

    function isReload() {
        timenow++;
        if (timenow >= timeReload) {
            timenow = 0;
            if (i === pieChart.series[0].data.length) {
                i = 0;
            }

            pieChart.series[0].data[i].select();
            pieChart.series[0].data[i].setVisible();
            i++;
        }
    }

    var t = setInterval("isReload()", 1000);
```

А ещё я хочу что бы при том когда выбирается кусок, что бы при этом ещё и выводилась аннотация к нему, как будто я навожу на него курсор. И я даже в документации нашёл у highcharts класс annotation, в свою очередь у которого есть метод setVisible. Но не могу понять как вызвается этот метод, если делаю как сейчас в моём коде `pieChart.series[0].data[i].setVisible();` тогда скрывается кусок или открывается в зависимости от того открыт он уже или нет. А как выводить аннотацию, подскажите кто нибудь пожалуйста.
Последний вариант:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Diagramm";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var pieChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["pieData"]))
        }],
    });

    var timeReload = 3;
    var timenow = 0;
    var i = 0;

    function isReload() {
        timenow++;
        if (timenow >= timeReload) {
            timenow = 0;
            if (i === pieChart.series[0].data.length) {
                i = 0;
            }

            var point = pieChart.series[0].points[i++];
            point.select();
            point.setState('hover');
            point.state = '';
            pieChart.tooltip.refresh(p);
            i++;
        }
    }

    var t = setInterval("isReload()", 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аннотации, которые вы нашли, это просто дополнительные метки на чарте. А то, что показывается, когда вы наводите на чарт, это тултипы. Вот их и надо обновлять.

```js
var data  = [
        { name : "FireFox", y : 45.0 },
        { name : "IE", y : 26.8 },
        { name : "Chrome", y : 12.8 },
        { name : "Safari", y : 8.5 },
        { name : "Opera", y : 6.2 },
        { name : "Others", y : 0.7 }
];

var pieChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: data
        }]
    });
    
    
var i  = 0;
setInterval(function(){        
    if (i == pieChart.series[0].points.length){
       i = 0;
    }
    
    var p =  pieChart.series[0].points[i++];
    p.select();
    p.setState('hover');
    p.state = '';    
    pieChart.tooltip.refresh(p);        
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: teran попробовал как вы написали, почему то тултип не появляется как у вас в коде. Мой код в вопросе.

Comment: @Андрей а вы консоль браузера откройте, и увидите, что в вашем коде есть опечатки.

Comment: terat большое спасибо, работает)